# How can I hide a divs border behind another div with css?

Tags: html, css

I want the border div to be "hidden" behind the circle and not cross through it. I thought `z-index` was the way to do things like this.

Any ideas?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/qs5xmege/1/

CSS and HTML

```css
.container {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
  border-radius:11px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  z-index: 100;
}
.border {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give `.circle` a `position:relative`, `z-index` works only with `position:relative`, `position:absolute` or `position: fixed`

```css
.container {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
  border-radius:11px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
.border {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` to `.circle`.

`z-index` need `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` vaue for `position`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:relative` of div circle and `z-index:2` ie. 1 more than `border` is enough

```
.circle {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 3px solid #FF0000;
    border-radius: 11px;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 22px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.container {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 3px solid #FF0000;
  border-radius: 11px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 22px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.border {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    .circle {
        background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 11px;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -68px;
    width: 22px;
    }
.border {
    border-right: thin solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
}
```